# Calculating distance (pythagoras)

Tags: mysql, sql, distance

Total SQL newb here. I've created two SQL tables, one containing information about hotels and the other containing information about attractions.

```
SELECT hotels.*, attractions.*,  
    ((ACOS(SIN(hotels.Hotel_Lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(attractions.Attraction_Lat * PI() / 180) +  
        COS(hotels.Hotel_Long * PI() / 180) * COS(attractions.Attraction_Long * PI() / 180) *  
        COS((hotels.Hotel_Long - attractions.Attraction_Long) * PI() / 180)) *   
        180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distance  
FROM hotels join attractions
```

This query returns 'Null' for distances. Any ideas why please? I have negative value longitudes if that makes a difference?

Comment: Yes, but which version of MySQL? The workbench is just an application that connects to MySQL.

Comment: Oh sorry, mysql community server version 5.6.17. Sound right?

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query you are currently using.

Comment: Please post the SQL as plain text, not an image link. Even better would be to make a sqlfiddle with sample data.

Comment: Your distance formula doesn't look right. You're calculating normal cartesian distance, not distance on a sphere. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographical_distance

Comment: See the query in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4741384/distance-between-two-coordinates-how-can-i-simplify-this-and-or-use-a-different?rq=1

Comment: Because you're using the wrong formula, your distances aren't in any useful units. Your formula treats degrees as units on the plane, and it's calculating distance in those units.

Comment: I see, would it be simpler for me to change the formula, or to change the units? This doesn't need to be huge, my data is very small.

Comment: If at least one of the value of the formula is `NULL` it'll spread to the results, and even if the formulata return a value it will be the direct route, not the road distance

Answer (score 0):

You can't calculate the distance like this, because it doesn't consider the curvature of the earth.

After a little bit of googling you would have got the following link: http://zcentric.com/2010/03/11/calculate-distance-in-mysql-with-latitude-and-longitude/ and there is the correct SQL Query:

```
SELECT ((ACOS(SIN($lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(`lat` * PI() / 180) + COS($lat * PI() / 180) * COS(`lat` * PI() / 180) * COS(($lon – `lon`) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance 
FROM `members` 
HAVING distance<=’10′ 
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

So for you it would look something like this:

```
SELECT h.*, a.*,
    ((ACOS(SIN(h.Hotel_Lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(a.Attractions_Lat * PI() / 180) +
        COS(h.Hotel_Long * PI() / 180) * COS(a.Attractions_Long * PI() / 180) *
        COS((h.Hotel_Long - a.Attractions_Long) * PI() / 180)) * 
        180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distance
FROM hotel h join attractions a
```

Comment: Really appreciate the help, thankyou. Do I need to change anything in the formula? I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: I might have a typo in it - what's the exact error?

Comment: 14:14:59 SELECT h.*, a.*, ((COS(SIN(h.Hotel_Lat * PI() / 180) * SIN(a.Attractions_Lat * PI() / 180) + COS(h.Hotel_Long * PI() / 180) * COS(a.Attractions_Long * PI() / 180) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515 as distance from hotel h join attractions a Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as distance from hotel h join attractions a' at line 4 0.000 sec

Comment: There was a bracket missing at the end of the formula - it's there now

Comment: SELECT hotels.*, attractions.*,  
    ((ACOS(SIN(hotels.Hotel_Lat * PI() / 180) *   SIN(attractions.Attraction_Lat * PI() / 180) +  
        COS(hotels.Hotel_Long * PI() / 180) *     COS(attractions.Attraction_Long * PI() / 180) *  
        COS((hotels.Hotel_Long - attractions.Attraction_Long) * PI() / 180)) * 
        180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) as distance  
FROM hotels join attractions

Comment: But it's bringing back Null in distance, any idea?

Comment: no, what you could do is - splitting the long formula into different columns to see which part evaluates to NULL - because that purt will make everything else NULL as well. However this should only happen if one of the columns used is NULL in your tables already - this doesn’t seem to be the case according to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you making this incredibly complicated for yourself? Just enable the [MySQL Geospatial extensions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/spatial-extensions.html) and [use ST_Distance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2013/10/21/using-the-new-spatial-functions-in-mysql-5-6-for-geo-enabled-applications/) to solve your problem:

```
SELECT hotels.*, a.*,  ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(hotels.Hotel_Lon, hotels.Hotel_Lat),  ST_MakePoint(a.Attractions_Long, a.Attractions_Lat) as distance FROM hotels join attractions a;
```

Do be aware, that mysql's St_Distance function does not take advantage of indices and only handles polar coordinates.

Hope it helps and if you have further problems, do leave a comment.

Comment: Because I don't have a clue what I am doing unfortunately. I can't even see how to enable extensions.

Comment: Please try the query I posted and report back?

Comment: 16:20:12 SELECT hotel.*, attraction.*,  ST_Distance(ST_MakePoint(hotel.long, hotel.lat),  ST_MakePoint(attraction.long, attraction.lat)  as distance FROM hotel join attraction a Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM hotel join attraction a' at line 3 0.000 sec
I changed it a bit because I made some new tables, specifying the lats and longs as a geometry datatype.

Comment: I literally started using this program this morning, I've had a look at fiddle but have no idea what to do with it. I can post screenshots if that helps?

Comment: On the left pane, you put your DDL statements to create your data, on the right, put SELECT 1 and "Run SQL". Put the resulting URL in a comment here and I'll look at it.

Comment: My apologies, I don't know how to write DDL statements, I just make the tables in workbench. I've only been given an assignment and no direction. This is the best I can do... http://imgur.com/APsVEJX

Comment: `mysqldump -d -u <username> -p<password> -h localhost <dbname>` will show you the DDL statements from the command line

Comment: Drop me a line on google talk -- hd1@jsc.d8u.us and we'll get this sorted