# iOS sqlite no such function: ACOS error

Tags: ios, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Query to get records based on Radius in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite)

I am using sqlite to save latitude,longitude and video path in my application. by passing the current latitude and longitude as parameter in the query. i need to sort the video paths based
on the proximity. I am using the following query to achieve this **SELECT  `videopath` , ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( 12.9833 ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lat ) ) * COS( RADIANS( lng ) - RADIANS( 77.5833 ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( 12.9833 ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM VideoPathsTable ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 30**. In sql this query executes fine but in sqlite i am getting the following error **no such function: ACOS** is there any other alternate way to do this. Please help me to solve this issue.I am using libsqlite3.0.dylib

Comment: There is a method that works on iOS, see http://daveaddey.com/?p=71 no need to add new columns. I would write it as an answer, but the editors have incorrectly marked this question as a duplicate (note to editors: the question you refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite is specific to Android "**I can't run custom functions with it as it's on Android**", please un-duplicate this question – we can run custom functions on iOS).

Comment: I think your question is answered by stephencelis here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825513/creating-custom-sqlite-functions-in-swift-alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this is not part of the standart SQLite: [Query to get records based on Radius in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite)

Check on SO before :-)

Comment: Actually that question is referring to Android, on iOS there are more options available and you don't have to create additional columns. You can add a custom function like so http://daveaddey.com/?p=71 it's really easy to do, and works with your existing structure.