# Creating custom sqlite functions in Swift alone

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift

How can a custom sqlite function be added in Swift?

The following SO question addresses the issue of using functions like acos and cos in an sqlite query involving coordinates:
[iOS sqlite no such function: ACOS error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124233/ios-sqlite-no-such-function-acos-error)

The suggestion is to add a custom function. But the example is given in Objective-C.  Other than bridging to Objective-C is there a native Swift function or library that allows the creation of custom functions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQLite.swift](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift) provides a type-safe Swift interface for [creating custom SQL functions](https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#custom-sql-functions) **(disclaimer: I wrote and maintain SQLite.swift)**. The current version bridges to Objective-C internally, though this is an implementation detail you can ignore. A future version will likely use Swift 2's function pointer API. And while you *can* use C function pointers in Swift 1.x with some `@objc_block` and `unsafeBitCast`, it's quite a bit worse to read and maintain.

The most basic way to create a `cos` function:

```
import SQLite
import Darwin

// opens a database connection
let db = Database()

// defines a "cos" function on the connection 
db.create(function: "cos", argc: 1, deterministic: true) { args in
    if let x = args[0] as? Double {
        return Darwin.cos(x)
    }
    return nil
}

println(db.scalar("SELECT cos(1.0)"))
// Optional(0.54030230586813977)
```

A more complex, safer example wherein SQLite.swift generates a type-safe interface to your database given a contract:

```
import SQLite
import Darwin

// opens a database connection
let db = Database()

// defines a "cos" function on the connection 
let cos: Expression<Double> -> Expression<Double> = (
    db.create(function: "cos", deterministic: true, Darwin.cos)
)

// builds a SQL expression for the column, "x"
let x = Expression<Double>("x")

// creates a query reference for the table, "table"
let table = db["table"]

// creates the table
db.create(table: table) { t in
    t.column(x)
}
// CREATE TABLE "table" ("x" REAL)

// inserts a row where "x" is 1.0
table.insert(x <- 1.0)
// INSERT INTO "table" ("x") VALUES (1.0)

// executes the query
for row in db.select(cos(x)) {
    println(row[cos(x)])
}
// SELECT "cos"("x") FROM "table"
```

Comment: Quick follow up is that in your example, a new db is made... and I understand that. And I understand how to act on a db once I have it. But I have an existing sqlite3 file. What is the db.open command for that (along the lines of the db create)...  in other words, how do I make db equal that file (or reference it) so I can then add the cos function and start working with the data? Thank you!

Comment: @JackAmoratis You can pass a path directly to the initializer. See the instructions here: https://github.com/stephencelis/SQLite.swift/blob/master/Documentation/Index.md#connecting-to-a-database

Comment: I like this answer and I feel it is the most helpful... except I cannot verify it because I cannot get the module to work using the manual install instructions on the github repo you linked to. I've tried for 2 hours now, uninstalling, reinstalling, restarting XCode. I am guessing it is something minor (it usually is, right?!) Have you recently reviewed your manual install instructions? Thanks.

Comment: @JackAmoratis I've recently installed with the same instructions and they should work. Try CocoaPods if you're still having trouble.

Comment: The issue seems to be... I downloaded the repo as a zip and unzipped it in my Downloads directory. I dragged in the projectfile from there, and everything works. But that is untenable for the long term. So I copied it into the project through the Finder and then newly dragged the project file into the existing project. That is where the error arises.

Answer (score 4):

Here is Swift 4 example how to bind closure into SQLite function with 1 argument which return uppercased string:

```
sqlite3_create_function(db, "utf8_upper".cString(using: .utf8), 1, SQLITE_UTF8, nil, { context, argc, arguments in
    let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, to: sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
    let argv = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arguments, count: Int(argc)))
    let param = String(cString: UnsafePointer(sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])))
    let result = param.uppercased()
    return sqlite3_result_text(context, result, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
}, nil, nil)
```

Comment: Perfect answer. Have been looking for this and could not find. Thanks!!! This should be the correct answer.