# Define a function in sqlite3 - swift

Tags: swift, sqlite

I am trying to define a `REGEXP` function in sqlite3 by using `sqlite3_create_function_v2`. but I don't know how to return the result.

```
sqlite3_create_function_v2(db, "REGEXP", 2, SQLITE_UTF8, nil,
    { context, argc, arguments in
        let argv = Array(UnsafeBufferPointer(start: arguments, count: Int(argc)))
        let pattern = String(cString: UnsafePointer(sqlite3_value_text(argv[0])))
        let text = String(cString: UnsafePointer(sqlite3_value_text(argv[1])))
        let reg = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: pattern, options: [])
        let match = reg.firstMatch(in: text, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: text.utf16.count))
    if match == nil {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    }, nil, nil, nil)
```

I need to search the database using regex like this:

```
let sql = "SELECT * FROM 'Books' WHERE bookID = 1 AND REGEXP('\(pattern)', text);"
var statement: OpaquePointer?

if sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
    while sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {
        if let unsafeText = sqlite3_column_text(statement, 3) {
            let text = String(cString: unsafeText)
            print(text)
        }
    }
} else {
    let errorMessage = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db))
    print("Query is not prepared \(errorMessage)")
}
```

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5071601/how-do-i-use-regex-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating custom sqlite functions in Swift alone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825513/creating-custom-sqlite-functions-in-swift-alone)

Comment: When looking at the duplicate question, have a look at the answer that uses `sqlite3_create_function`, not the answer using a 3rd party Swift SQLite library.