# Android and distance between two point using sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, distance

I am looking for good solution to calculate distance between two points.

I want to sort by distance my Geo points.

I have:

```
Cursor c = database.rawQuery("SELECT name,latitude,longitude,((longitude-21.15)*(longitude-21.15) +(latitude-54.05)*(latitude-54.05)) AS len FROM Object ORDER BY len;", null);
```

But this is wrong solution...
Distance is wrong...

Please help me.

Comment: `;` in the query seems wrong to me.

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite/9536914#9536914

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have here is that you're combining:

- GPS coordinates (WGS84) that are used to represent a point on a sphere.
- Pythagoras theorem, requires a 2D rectangular coordinate system, to determine distance.

This will simply not work if you're after accuracy!

Here are some options that I've used.

**Option 1 - Use great circle distance**

This formula is used to calculate the distance in meters between two GPS co-ordinates

Android provides a function [distanceBetween](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float%5B%5D%29) as part of the android.location.Location class to assist with this.

The downside is you have to pull out all your points from SQLite in order to calculate the distance.

I have also seen some hybrids such as:

- treating WGS84 (GPS) as rectangular
- specifying a zones in your db to limit the size of data you pull out when calculating distance.

and then using the distanceBetween function to further filter the results.

**Option 2 - Use a rectangular coordinate system**

If your distances are small then you can solve this problem is by storing the database points in UTM which is rectangular.

Using a formula almost identical, but using easting and northings, the SQLite db can be used to provide the x closest points to a UTM point. Once these points are identified the square-root function can be performed on the x results to get the distance in meters.

**Huh?**

There are some caveats about using UTM also. It might help you looking at [Calculating Distance Between Two Sets of Coordinates](http://support.groundspeak.com/index.php?pg=kb.page&id=211)

So your solution ultimately depends on your application and is a compromise between speed and accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

You are calculating the *square* of the distance. Since SQLite doesn't have a square-root function, you will need to calculate this in your Java code.

If all you need is to *sort* by distance, then your current code is fine.

Comment: The problem is that they are geo points.
When counting in the code distance, sort is bad.

Comment: If you need to calculate geodesic distance, you have to do it in Java. Or try that (I've never tested it so good luck): https://code.google.com/p/spatialite-android/

Answer (score -1):

You can use static method *distanceBetween* of **android.location.Location** class. Then based on calculated distance you can produce some sorted collection of object like SortedMap.