# calculate distance between a location and a list of locations

Tags: java, android, ios, performance, location

I have a list of locations , following this pattern:

```
[1] = {lat = -40.2452, longitude = -76.2489},
[2] = {lat = -40.2452, longitude = -76.2489},
[3] = {lat = -40.2452, longitude = -76.2489},
[4] = {lat = -40.2452, longitude = -76.2489}
```

and a localition

```
location = {lat = -40.2452, longitude = -76.2489}
```

and I want to calculate Which of the locations this Within the distance.

I found a formula that calculates the distance between two points.

but if this list is big!

is there any faster way?

or you can go through the list in a loop ?

```
FOR LOCATION IN LISTLOCATION DO
    IF GETDISTANCE(LOCATION, LOCATION2) <= DISTANCE
        SAVE THIS LOCATION
    END
END
```

These values are a example

Comment: If you're worried about performance, and you're on Android, why not put your data into a SQLite database, and query. More in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite

Comment: I know is for example purpose, but all your locations are the same.

Comment: Your example array has all the same items. If there is a high probability that there will be a lot of duplicate items, removing them before calling `GETDISTANCE(LOCATION, LOCATION2) ` them would increase performance.

Comment: I request to a server which are clients next and send my location, and the server does this calculation and returns a list

Comment: these values ​​are an example

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to check each and every point, no other option. The distance formula (Haversine) is indeed slow, since it uses few trigonometric functions. What you actually want is to plot a circle around your point, whose radius `R` is the distance, and check for each point if it's inside that circle:
[image]

The problem is that your point are given as (lat, long) pair, not (x,y) pair, so you can't use "regular" trigonometric methods, like the circle's equation.
Instead, you have to find a square that bounds that circle. Go 90 degrees to the north and south, find the upper and lower longitudes of that square. Do the same to rhe east and west, find the upper and lower latitudes:
[image]

Now you can check for each point if it's inside the box, and you can do it easily with simple comparsions:

```
if lon > lon1 and lon < lon2
   and lat > lat2 and lat < lat1
```

which is really computionally cheap.
The only problem is with points that are inside the blue area:
[image]

They are inside the square but not inside the circle, so you'll have to use the Haversine formula for them.
If most of your points are not in the square, this method will save you time, because eliminating them is pretty easy.

Comment: If I continue using the same formula , a server could perform the calculation constantly ?

Comment: I request to a server which are clients next and send my location, and the server does this calculation and returns a list

Comment: You've asked for a faster way and I think that my solution is faster than using the Haversine formula for each point. It's up to you to decide which method to use and whether to do it at the server or the client.

Comment: @nasch These are the points that thedistance between them and the center is greater than R.

Comment: Ah of course, so you're calculating the distance for every point inside the square, rather than every point in the list.  Makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Android then you can use the ["distanceBetween" method of the Location class](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html?hl=es#distanceBetween%28double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[]%29).
This method has it's implementation in Java (you can do a loop to test the distance between your location and the location list elements), so if you want higher performance you should do it natively (NDK). If you do it natevely you should pass the complete list to the native method and not one by one because the context change between the virtual and the native environment can be costly.