# How to check if user in one of marker (from 10000 of markers) everytime user change location in google map android?

Tags: android, dictionary, geometry, marker

How to check if user in one of marker (from 10000 of markers), everytime user change location ?
I know how to check with small of markers, i can check one by one with distanceTo, but how to check one by one from 10000 of marker and everytime if user moving ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How long does it take to go through the list once?  If you can manage that, then you could make a smaller list of markers with x meters of the user.  Keep track of how far the user has moved, and once they get near or at x meters, recalculate the list.  That depends on calculating the whole list now and then being a manageable operation.

Here are some other ideas about how to do it faster:

[Query to get records based on Radius in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3126830/query-to-get-records-based-on-radius-in-sqlite)

[calculate distance between a location and a list of locations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37664500/calculate-distance-between-a-location-and-a-list-of-locations)